# In writing Chrome extensions, how is "var i in windows" (within a callback function(windows)) compiled?

Tags: javascript

The array of Window windows which is passed to the callback has a number of properties, so how does the compiler know what "var i in windows" is referring to?

The code snippet looks like this:

```
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(windows) {
        for (var i in windows) {
             var tabs = windows[i].tabs;
```

In the next line `windows[i].tabs` windows is being passed as an array, so I understand how that works but not `var i in windows`.

Comment: This is plain javascript. Not specific to chrome or extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the best approach, but it works for `Array`.

You should read the [MDN entry on `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to understand how it works.

This iterates over *enumerable* properties of an object.

That explains why things like `windows.length` do not get into the loop. They are simply defined by the Array to be non-enumerable by the means of `.propertyIsEnumerable()`, and the same for inherited things:

> Objects created from built–in constructors like `Array` and `Object` have inherited non–enumerable properties from `Object.prototype` and `String.prototype`, such as `String`'s `indexOf()` method or Object's `toString()` method.

And about arrays specifically:

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.

Further reading:

- [`Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)
- [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Note that documentation recommends using a standard `for` loop, a `for...of` loop or `.forEach()` in case of arrays.

Comment: Thank you! I agree it does not seem like some kind of "best practice", so what do you suggest would be a better approach? And if an object has different enumerable properties, which will it loop over?

Comment: I think a standard `for` loop does not seem elegant, though it's the most robust; I would use `.forEach()`. However, as long as nobody messed with the array, `for...in` is a valid approach. ES6's [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) seems even more elegant, and Chrome supports it already.

Comment: So,  something like `for length of Array` or `for size of Array` (assuming it has a length/size property)?

Comment: No. `for...of` takes a variable to assign and an object. `for whatever of obj` and `for size of obj` is the same, regardless whether `obj.size` exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the properties of your parameter `windows` are defined, but if you don't get them on the `for(var i in windows)` it means that they aren't defined as usual properties like this :

```
windows.prop = "value";
windows['prop'] = "value";
```

One way of defining a propety which you can't find using your loop is using the `Object.defineProperty` , check this example :

```
Object.defineProperty( windows, 'prop', { 
   get : function () { 
       return 'value';
   }
});
```

Now when you use a `for(var i in windows)` loop, you won't get the property `prop`

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you can access properties of an object using either the dot notation or the squared brackets notation.

```
var a = {
    b = 'c'
};

a.b === a['b']; // true
```

So in the snippet you're showing, the for loop loops over all indices of the array (in fact it will also loop over all properties on the array, so I don't understand why a `for(var i = 0; ...)` solution isn't used here). And then it simply accesses the elements of the array by requesting the property with the squared brackets notation.

AFAICT an alternative notation of the snippet you're showing would be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++){
    var tabs = windows[i].tabs;
}
```

Assuming `windows` is indeed an array.